# how do I do to the conditional appears in the console.log?

Tags: function, conditional-statements

the conditional doesn´t work when the bmi < 18.5

```
function bmiCalculator (weight, height) {
   var ecuation= (weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
 return Math.round(ecuation);
}

if(bmiCalculator < 18.5){
 console.log("you are so underweight")
}


console.log(bmiCalculator(20,2.20))
```

if bmi < 18.5 and I run the code it should appear "you are so underweight". instead of that it appears 4

Comment: You are comparing a function definition to a number. That's not going to work. You need to compare the result of the function call.

Comment: you are right , I didn´t think about it , thank you